# Metrics doesn't decay when no values are reported

Tags: codahale-metrics

I am using codahale metrics for monitoring purposes. Lets say there is a spike in latency at some point and later there are no values reported due to attribute that there are no traffic, the value in the graph stays as is(I am using a histogram). At times it gives a notion that the spike remains and we might need to address it, but it actually means that no values are reported after that and hence the graph doesn't decay. Am I missing any config parameter in this case or is the behaviour expected?

The way we update the metrics is
metrics.processingTime.update(processingTime);

So, when there is no traffic, we don't update this metric.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the histogram takes into consideration datapoints from the past (for an irregular period of time) in order to display a statistical image of the data. 
When there are no new datapoints, only the outlier is taken into consideration and averaged on and on.

The meters have the same behavior, displaying the data through moving averages of 1,5,15 minutes. 
The solution in the histogram case is to use HDRhistogram and flush it periodically.